# Jekyll Page data does not persist

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

Jekyll version 2.5.3

We are trying to write a plugin to promote content that is agnostic as to whether or not its a page or a post. However there is some difference between pages and posts that is not clear.

```
  # this does not work
  site.pages.each do |page|
    # this does not show up in liquid
    page.data['baz'] = 'Foo'
  end

  # this does work
  site.posts.each do |post|
    # this does show up in liquid
    post.data['baz'] = 'Bar'
  end
```

Any ideas as to why mutating the `.data` hash for posts is accessible in liquid, but mutating the `.data` hash for pages has no effect?

We've also tested this with `.data["title"]` and it has an effect on `posts` but `page` titles are uneffected.

---

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
   <div class="postbaz">{{ post.baz }}</div>
{% endfor %}

{% for page in site.pages %}
   <div class="pagebaz">{{ page.baz }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

yields

```
<div class="postbaz">Foo</div>
<div class="postbaz">Foo</div>
<div class="postbaz">Foo</div>
<div class="pagebaz"></div>
<div class="pagebaz"></div>
```

Comment: In my prod code it was `page`. In my reproduction code it was `pages`, good catch; I moved it back to `page` and have the same problem.

Comment: @Fresheyeball do you have any update on that question?

Comment: Not since the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something. Adding values to `data` works perfectly fine both for pages and posts.

See [my repository](https://bitbucket.org/eugzol/jekyll_test/src) for reference.

[Here](https://bitbucket.org/eugzol/jekyll_test/src/8445df1f3be4af18095cdad1b06578a6db4adb8b/_plugins/foo.rb?at=master) I add 'foo' attribute to all pages and posts

**_plugins/foo.rb**

```
module Foo
  class Generator < Jekyll::Generator
    def generate(site)
      puts "Our plugin is running"
      puts site.pages.inspect
      puts site.posts.inspect
      site.pages.each do |page|
        page.data['foo'] = 'bar'
      end
      site.posts.each do |post|
        post.data['foo'] = 'bar'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here I add 'foo' to posts layout:

**post.html**

```
<article class="post-content">
  {{ content }}
  {{ page.foo }}
</article>
```

And to [pages layout](https://bitbucket.org/eugzol/jekyll_test/src/8445df1f3be4af18095cdad1b06578a6db4adb8b/_layouts/page.html?at=master#page.html-12):

**page.html**

```
<article class="post-content">
  {{ content }}
  {{ page.foo }}
</article>
```

After I ran `jekyll b` I can see output in both [post](https://bitbucket.org/eugzol/jekyll_test/src/92752fef5c0fa5fe72e039a78bf3dd658468d1c3/_site/jekyll/update/2015/08/04/welcome-to-jekyll.html?at=master#welcome-to-jekyll.html-80) and [page](https://bitbucket.org/eugzol/jekyll_test/src/92752fef5c0fa5fe72e039a78bf3dd658468d1c3/_site/about/index.html?at=master#index.html-71), just where I expect them to be.

In separate branch I re-created your setup, where you iterate over all pages and posts:

**default.html ([source](https://bitbucket.org/eugzol/jekyll_test/src/8375d80c748afb0eb9066f19665bc4dabee6c40f/_layouts/default.html?at=modified_index_html#default.html-18))**

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
   <div class="postbaz">{{ post.foo }}</div>
{% endfor %}

{% for page in site.pages %}
   <div class="pagebaz">{{ page.foo }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

**_plugins/foo.rb ([source](https://bitbucket.org/eugzol/jekyll_test/src/8375d80c748afb0eb9066f19665bc4dabee6c40f/_plugins/foo.rb?at=modified_index_html))**

```
site.pages.each do |page|
  page.data['foo'] = 'bar'
end
site.posts.each do |post|
  post.data['foo'] = 'baz'
end
```

(Notice the property is 'bar' for page, and 'baz' for post.)

It renders as expected:

**site/index.html ([source](https://bitbucket.org/eugzol/jekyll_test/src/8375d80c748afb0eb9066f19665bc4dabee6c40f/_site/index.html?at=modified_index_html#index.html-140))**

```
<div class="postbaz">baz</div>



<div class="pagebaz">bar</div>

<div class="pagebaz">bar</div>

<div class="pagebaz">bar</div>

<div class="pagebaz">bar</div>
```

Comment: You never know what lines a man can cross for a 50-rep. bounty. I even built a repository for you! :D